# Converting a text input to a select element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm doing some front end development on a hosted e-commerce platform. The system sends a text input for the customer to choose the quantity of items they want to add to their cart, but I would prefer a select. I don't have access to the markup the system spits out in this regard, so I'd like to use JavaScript to change the text *input* to a *select* element.

I used jQuery to remove the select and duplicate the input element with a select with the right choices, but when I try to add something to my cart, only one item is added, regardless of the choice in the select.

Here's the native markup:

```
<div id="buy-buttons">
  <label>Quantity:</label>
  <input name="txtQuantity" type="text" value="1" id="txtQuantity" class="ProductDetailsQuantityTextBox">
  <input type="submit" name="btnAddToCart" value="Add To Cart" id="btnAddToCart" class="ProductDetailsAddToCartButton ThemeButton AddToCartThemeButton ProductDetailsAddToCartThemeButton">
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm running to update my markup.

```
 $("#txtQuantity").remove();
 $("#buy-buttons").append('<select id="txtQuantity" type="text" value="1" class="ProductDetailsQuantityTextBox"></select>');
 $("#txtQuantity").append('<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>');
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working? Shouldn't the select be submitting the information to through the form in the same way as the text input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't set the field name. Add `name='txtQuantity'` to the select.  Without a name attribute the value of the field will not get posted back to the server.

Also rather than setting `value='1'` on the select (which isn't doing anything), add `selected='selected'` to the first option.  The result is the same as by default the first option is selected.

You are presumably ending up with the select after the submit button with the above code. However that has been covered in another answer.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I missed that attribute.

Answer (score 40):

Use `replaceWith` instead of `remove` and `append`.  Also the `type` attribute on the `<select>` is unnecessary and the `<option>` nodes should be within the `<select>`.  Here's the docs on `replaceWith` - http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/.

```
$("#txtQuantity")
    .replaceWith('<select id="txtQuantity" name="txtQuantity" class="ProductDetailsQuantityTextBox">' +
          '<option value="1">1</option>' +
          '<option value="2">2</option>' +
          '<option value="3">3</option>' +
          '<option value="4">4</option>' +
          '<option value="5">5</option>' +
        '</select>');
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this jQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an dropdown/select list and you just want to add an item to it from a label/textbox then you can try this :

```
 if ($(textBoxID).val() != '') {
                $(dropDownID)
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr('value', ($(textBoxID).val()))
                            .text($(textBoxID).val())).val($(textBoxID).val())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `type` and `value` attributes from the `<select>`, and add the `name="txtQuantity"` attribute that you left out.