# jquery replace text field value with select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171685/converting-a-text-input-to-a-select-with-javascript) and applied the following code to replace a text field with a HTML select option.

```
$("#id_reason").replaceWith(
    '<select id="id_reason" name="id_reason" onchange="changeReason();"' +
        '<option value="0">Select a Reason</option>' +
        '<option value="General Query">General Query</option>' +
        '<option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>' +
        '<option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>' +
        '<option value="Translation">Translation</option>' +
        '<option selected value="Registration">Registration</option>' +
        '<option selected value="Subscription">Subscription</option>' +
        '<option selected value="Other">Other</option>' +
    '</select>');

    function changeReason() {

        //apply some code here I think!

    }
```

The issue I have is that the form won't recognise the selected value of the reason select list b/c the form validation does not allow the reason value to be blank.

**How do I write the code to apply the value of the select option to be the value that is to be applied to the reason field when the form is submitted?**

I have tried renaming the select list to id_reason1, but cannot figure out how to apply the selected value to the field when the form is submitted.

Comment: Just get the value of the selected option (or the select itself, which should be the same), and assign it as the value of the text field …?

Comment: CBore, how? b/c i cannot get it to work.

Comment: As Cbroe said: `document.getElementById("id_reason").value` should get you the reason value. Adding the `selected` attribute to one of the options should give a standard value. Use `disabled` attribute on the first option to not allow selection after the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    $("#id_reason").replaceWith(
        '<select id="id_reason" name="reason">' +
            '<option value="">Select a Reason</option>' +
            '<option value="General Query">General Query</option>' +
            '<option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>' +
            '<option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>' +
            '<option value="Translation">Translation</option>' +
            '<option value="Subscription">Subscription</option>' +
            '<option value="Registration">Registration</option>' +
            '<option value="Other">Other</option>' +
        '</select>');
```

You have two issues:

1. you have a typo - neglected to close the select tag; and
2. make the value of the 1st option nothing as shown.