# Converting Text field to drop down field

Tags: html, dropdown

I tried to make the text field in dropdown

Original

```
<div class="search-box-left">Loan Tenure (Year)</div>
                    <div class="search-box-right">
                    <input name='tenure' type='text' value='' maxlength='10'  style='width:160px; font-weight:bold; font-size:11px; color:#373737; height:20px;' onkeypress = 'return isNumberKey(event);' onchange='calculateamortization(document.formamortization);'/>                           
                    </div>
```

and use below the way of option to create dropdown

```
<div class="search-box-left">Loan Tenure (Year)</div>
                    <div class="search-box-right">
                    <select id='tenure' name='tenure' style=" height:25px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#4c4c4c; width:80px;' onchange='calculateamortization(document.formamortization);'>                                   
                        <option value=''>Loan Tenure</option>
                        <option value=12 >1 Year</option>
                        <option value=24 >2 Year</option>
                        <option value=36 >3 Year</option>
                        <option value=48 >4 Year</option>
                        <option value=60 >5 Year</option>
                        <option value=72 >6 Year</option>
                        <option value=84 >7 Year</option>
                        </select>&nbsp;                                         
                    </div>
```

But somehow seems an error as drop down not working
Can any one suggest or help on the mistake in same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a text input to a select element with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171685/converting-a-text-input-to-a-select-element-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5's Datalist tag.

```
<datalist id="Loan Tenure" placeholder="Loan Tenure">
   <option value="1 Year">
   <option value="2 Year">
   <option value="3 Year">
   <option value="4 Year">
   <option value="5 Year">
   <option value="6 Year">
   <option value="7 Year">
</datalist>
```

You can specify predifined options in datalist.

Datalist provides autocomplete feature to input elements.